# Stop and resume (or just restart) with Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with controlling stop and return to the game based on Timeout. My code:

```
var state = true, timer;

function block(isOn) {
    if (isOn) {
        $('#block').click(function () {
            $(this).fadeOut(1200, function () {
                state = true;
                timer = setInterval(playGame, 500);
            });
        });
    } else {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('#block').fadeIn(1200, function () {
            block(true);
        });
    }
}

function playGame() {
    if (state) {
        (repeated game instructions)
    } else {
        block(false);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    block(true);
    $('#refresh').click(function () {
        state = false;
    });
});
```

Block is something like my start page and break page. Game starts with block set on `true`, on click game starts with Interval. But on click on #stop game stops by change of state and I want to reset timer by `clearInterval`. Then I'm showing again `block(true)`. It works, but when player again clicks on `#block` to return to game it starts with something like double speed. It looks like there are two instances of `playGame` function working at same time. I don't know what it is, maybe I'm using Interval inappropriately.

**Edit**
Thanks Antony, but change to setInterval did not solve my problem. I change my blockUp and blockDown to one function. I have updated code above to my actual progress.

I tried change `clearInterval(timer);` to `timer = null;` and `delete window.timer;` . Then i start to google about restarting setInterval and i see that this is serious problem. My game uses many jquery objects so i don't want to create array of timer's, i'm looking for economical solution :)

Comment: It looks like you should use `setInterval` instead of `setTimout`. `playGame()` calls itself every 500ms if `state == true`. It seems easier to use `clearInterval` when `state == false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to unbind the click event from `#block` each time you stop the game because a new click handler is registered each time you click on play.

```
$('#refresh').click(function () {
    state = false;
    $('#block').off('click'); // flushes every click bound to `#block`
});
```

Here is how to unbind handlers one by one :

```
var handler1, handler2;
$('#block').click(handler1 = function () { alert(1); });
$('#block').click(handler2 = function () { alert(2); });
// one click shows "1" then "2"
$('#block').off('click', handler1);
// one click shows "2"
```

Comment: Oh... thank you sir! I can't believe that solution is so logical.

Comment: Big thanks, really. It stopped my work on almost 20 hours. And I wasn't expected so detailed answer :)